# Facebook iOS SDK login not functioning - NSException

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

Followed numerous Facebook iOS SDK login guides including:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3
- http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/

With accurate implementations of the Facebook and other guides the same problem is still occurring. When running the application the Log in button is clicked and then an NSException occurs at the start of the AppDelegate class (Error: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"). The button as a result does nothing, and does not open another window to the Facebook login page. The simulator can use the internet and also the code and Info.plist has all the right data and code.

Does the Facebook app have to be live to the public be logged into from the app? The app online is in developer mode.

Comment: Do you have all the permissions? Are you using Facebook's new SDK? Do you have a stack trace at your server?

Comment: I re-looked at the stack trace console and it said couldn't find me FacebookAppID. What happened is I edited the Tests folders Info.plist instead of the main one. Stupidity at its finest today! Thanks

Comment: Based on your comment I have written an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that the Facebook App ID was not found. Looking at the stack trace was revealing the problem, which was subsequently fixed.