# faceBook login :terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am developing an app for facebook login  i followed all the instructions in facebook developer page

all is working fine.But while running facebook login app crashes and showed

```
    class appdelegate uiresponder uiapplicationdelegate{ 


thread 1 signal sigabrt on this line in delegate
```

Here's the error in more detail:

```
2016-07-19 03:15:54.298 wifiedProject[1998:177844] -[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b74c1e0
2016-07-19 03:15:54.342 wifiedProject[1998:177844] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b74c1e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00723494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02afbe02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0072d253 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0066289d ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0066246e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   wifiedProject                       0x000ce9cb _TFC13wifiedProject14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 763
    6   wifiedProject                       0x000ced32 _TToFC13wifiedProject14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    7   UIKit                               0x017a1b72 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 44
    8   UIKit                               0x017a6692 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1384
    9   UIKit                               0x017a6ab1 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    10  UIKit                               0x01654340 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 69
    11  UIKit                               0x01654a5d -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 304
    12  UIKit                               0x01654e13 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    13  UIKit                               0x01668551 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
    14  UIKit                               0x015cc7ef -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4190
    15  UIKit                               0x015d3f0f -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2010
    16  UIKit                               0x015f9b2c __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3246 + 68
    17  UIKit                               0x015d0b8a -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 163
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x05602110 __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x05601be7 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0561f27f __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 23
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0561f0ab -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 174
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0561f4fa -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x0561e7e8 FBSSerialQueueRunLoopSourceHandler + 33
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00635e5f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0062baeb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0062af08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0062a846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0062a65b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    29  UIKit                               0x015d02da -[UIApplication _run] + 540
    30  UIKit                               0x015d5eb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
    31  wifiedProject                       0x000d1321 main + 145
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x0351ba25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I searched more on this but all of them said to check the connections on UIView but I have one small view on the view controller and connected properly

my view controller  is

```
    import UIKit
    import FBSDKCoreKit
    import FBSDKLoginKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController ,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
    {


        @IBOutlet weak var login: FBSDKLoginButton!



           override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()==nil){
                print("User not logged in")
            } else {
                print("Logged in")
            }
            login.delegate = self
            login.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]

        }

        override func didReceiveMe

moryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!,didCompleteWithResult result : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
    {
        print("logged in")

    }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("loggeed out")

    }
```

my delegate is

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                                                                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url:NSURL,sourceApplication:String?,annotation:AnyObject?) ->
        Bool{

   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL:url,sourceApplication:sourceApplication,annotation:annotation)

    // Add any custom logic here.


    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "demoapp.ios.test.wifiedProject" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("wifiedProject", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

when I am  running my app the app is crashed. Can any one help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510607/facebook-ios-sdk-login-not-functioning-nsexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check once the `FBSDKLoginButton` is connection is established or not , if everything is correct check once are you added the delegate to your current class or not, for e.g, `login.delegate  = self`

> make sure you set the Class in the identity inspector to the correct Class.  That was my issue. Probably the most forgotten thing to do in Xcode.

**updated**

you forget to conform the delegate to current class

```
 loginView.delegate = self
```

at the same time ensure are you connected the delegate from attributed Inspector to current class

Comment: thank you for your answer ,the facebook sdk was full of objective c but i did swift project is there anything to do extra thing @Anbu.karthik

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy :    no need , your code is fine , the execptiion says the unknown delegate has fired, so check once your connection is probley connected or not at the same time check once the delegate has connected or not, thats all

Comment: But I am getting these errors while adding "FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate" to viewController class as I am new to ios development I coud not find the correct error place@Anbu.karthik

Comment: for step by step integartion see this https://dheerajsingh5792.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/facebook-sdk-ios-swift-cocoapods/

Comment: I did n't do the step Bridging-Header as that page mentioned Do i want to create Bridging-Header@Anbu.karthik

Comment: if you are used the conversion from objective C to swift integrate  Bridging-Header else no need\

Comment: "conversion from objective C to swift " means sorry to ask too many questions I downloaded the facebook sdk of objective c @Anbu.karthik

Comment: then you need to implement the bridge header , when u add the facebook sdk from outside to your project it automatically ask the bridge header creation part

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy - r u tehre

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy  if my answer is useful accept the answer , it is useful in future

Comment: @sathyachinnasamy  - tanq

Answer (score 0):

unrecognized selector sent to instance Occurs due to passing wrong type of parameter to the method. Please check whether you are passing correct type of parameter to the method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I am very new to ios development can you say me the clera answer I could not understand what you said @ vishal sonawane

Comment: It means, lets say we have a method called sayHello(NSString*)name; This method takes NSString as parameter and if you pass anything else like id or int to this method, then you will get unrecognized selector sent to instance error.